# How to add whl file on pip requirements files?

Tags: python, pip, package-managers, requirements

Assuming you created a whl of a proprietary project and would like to reuse it in another python project, how to indicate it via a relative path in a pip file without exposing whl online?

Although there is no direct description for this problem, from the  documentation (https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html) I have tried the following:

1. Indicate using -e file:

   > ./folder/my-project-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl#egg=my-project==0.1.0
   >   got> NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory
2. Indicate using file:

   > ./folder/my-project-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl#egg=my-project==0.1.0
   >   got> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
   >   '/folder/my-project-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl'

   It seems to seek the file on the root folder instead of the relative one.
3. Indicate without file:

   > folder/my-project-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl got> Invalid
   >   requirement: 'folder/my-project-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl'

   It looks like a path. Does it exist ?

It appears that if I indicate the folder instead it will work.
But as this is not the case, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
numpy
pandas
file:./folder/my-project-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl#egg=my-project==0.1.0
```

Pip install whl file using relative path with success!

Comment: just do "python pip install whlfile"

Comment: you can create a pypi server in your work enviroment,and upload that whl file there , let the people download from there when they use pip,

Comment: the whole installation process is performed in the publication of an azure function with the func azure functionapp publish option --build-native-deps and so I have no way to run the pip install inside the docker which it automatically generates